# Security issues related to storing secrets in scripts

Tags: unix, passwords, script, environment-variables

Let's say you have a program you want to run unattended, as root, which requires a secret (such as a passphrase; something you don't want other people to find out), which can be read from an environment variable. One way of accomplishing this would be to create a script like the following, and run it from root's crontab.

```
#!/bin/bash
export SECRET='my_secret'
/usr/bin/some_program
export SECRET=
```

Okay, so I can think of two security issues here.

First, someone could find the value of `$SECRET` by reading the script. Using `chmod 700` should take care of that.

Second, someone could use something like `ps ae` while `some_program` is running. However, if the script is running as root, only root (or sudoers) can see its environment, right?

Am I correct in believing the value of `$SECRET` can only be found by root or sudoers? Are there other security issues?

And, to make all this a little less abstract, [this](http://www.randys.org/2007/11/16/how-to-automated-backups-to-amazon-s-s3-with-duplicity/) is what got me thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a script that will only ever run on your own box?

Modern Linux defaults environment variables to only being visible to root or yourself, but that's not portable.  Various other OSes either can't filter them, or don't filter them by default.

Comment: Ah, there we go. Now I see why this would be a security problem in the general case. (In my case, this script will only ever run on my box.)

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts would be to avoid exporting pass-phrases at all times.
[**duplicity**](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html) seems has an option '`--use-agent`' that might help here.

> If this option is specified, then '`--use-agent`' is passed to the GnuPG encryption process and it will turn off any passphrase interaction with the user with respect to '`--encrypt-key`' or '`--sign-key`'.

---

Update: These are my biased opinions.

- A script should not cause security information to be exported in to the environment
- If you are not working with a special application (like `duplicity`),
  it would be easier to avoid the problem from my previous point by just shifting to the user-agent based mechanism (`ssh` has one for example, and I expected `duplicity` to have one -- which it did)
- the `secret` information is better (in a relative sense) protected with unix-access attributes under the application private data (I refer to things like `.ssh/id_dsa`)

Comment: I have some gripes with that answer. ;)

1. It didn't answer my question. I am not trying to make some script more secure, I am trying to understand *if* and *why* I should. Sorry if my question was unclear.

2. It only addresses the specific situation where some_program is duplicity.